# Rails: filtering based on a child & parent's attribute calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 2 associated tables and would like to apply a filter based on tshirts (child table) length attribute which is +/- %5 of the parent object Student's height attribute

Unfortunately I receive an undefined method error for the parent table's name.

DB TABLES:

```
Student
------
id
name
height

Tshirt
------
id
color
student_id
length
```

MODELS:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tshirts

class Tshirt < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student
    def self.suitablesize
       joins(:student).where('length < ? AND length > ?', (1.05*self.student.height),(0.95*self.student.height))
    end
```

Controller:

```
def index
@tshirts = Tshirt.all.suitablesize
end
```

Error Message:

```
undefined method `student' for #<Class:0xc88cdc0>
```

**EDIT:** 
I would like to get all tshirts which are suitable which are suitabile to owner student(s). Hence I do not want to find a single student to be an input parameter to scope method. Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You won't need to use `Tshirt.all.suitablesize`. `Tshirt.suitablesize` suffices as it will already return an ActiveRecord scope and thus `all` is a NoOp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation for the error**

You are calling `student` on the `Tshirt` class, although it is an instant method:

```
joins(:student).where('length < ? AND length > ?', (1.05*self.student.height),(0.95*self.student.height))
```

Here `self.student` is the offending part.

**Option 1: Shirts of a single student**

If you want to take a student's height into account you would have to change the scope method to take a parameter:

```
def self.suitablesize(student)
   where('length < ? AND length > ?', (1.05*student.height),(0.95*student.height))
end
```

And then provide the student in your controller method

```
def index
  @tshirts = Tshirt.suitablesize([SOME STUDENT INSTANCE])
end
```

The part where I inserted `[SOME STUDENT INSTANCE]` would need to be a student instance that was e.g. retrieved via a parameter provided by the request before

```
def index
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @tshirts = Tshirt.suitablesize(@student)
end
```

The exact parameter depends on your application (amongst other things the [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)) so I can only offer general pointers.

**Option 2: Shirts of all students**

If it is not desired to find suitable shirts for an individual student one would have to place the calculations into the database:

```
def self.suitable_size
 joins(:student)
   .where('tshirts.length < 1.05 * students.height AND tshirts.length > 0.95 * students.height')
end
```

This would then return all shirts belonging to a student where the shirts length is +/- 5% of the students height.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I would like to get all tshirts which are suitable which are suitabile to owner student(s). Hence I do not want to find a single student to be an input parameter to scope method

Comment: @Tolga I updated the answer to include a part about how to find all shirts not only those of a single student